# es6katas.org Kata #6: arrow functions - binding

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I am learning ECMAScript6 in [es6katas.org](http://es6katas.org), which is great and highly recommended. I am currently stuck at [this](http://tddbin.com/?524#?kata=es6/language/arrow-functions/binding) pretty basic kata about arrow function. I can't seem to understand what the author meant in the second test:

```
class LexicallyBound {

    getFunction() {
        return () => {
              return new LexicallyBound();
        }
    }

    getArgumentsFunction() {
        return function() {return arguments}
    }

}

it('bound at definition time, use `=>` ', function() {
    var bound = new LexicallyBound();
    var fn = bound.getFunction();

    assert.strictEqual(fn(), bound);
});
```

Can someone assist in figuring it out?

Comment: Please also include the code of `LexicallyBound` for completness.

Comment: added now, thank you for your comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it wanted you to change `getFunction` to return `this`.

Reason: Fat arrow function's `this` is bounded to the defining context (the `bound` object) when it was defined - when `bound` was created - instead of having a dynamic `this` like normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

es6katas has moved to [jskatas.org](https://jskatas.org) and also covers more than ES6, starting even at some ES1 stuff, which is still valid JS.